# Capturing lifetimes in rust macro_rules

Tags: macros, rust

In macro_rules! you can state the different types of things to parse after the colon (such as $x:ident for identifiers, or $y:ty for types), however I am confused as to how I would declare that I want to capture a lifetime, like 'a or 'static. Is this possible right now?

Answer (score 4):

You can capture lifetimes in macros with the `lifetime` specifier:

```rust
macro_rules! match_lifetimes {
    ( $( lt:lifetime ),+ ) => {}
}

match_lifetimes!( 'a, 'b, 'static, 'hello );
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20std%3A%3Astringify%3B%0A%0Amacro_rules!%20match_lifetime%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%24(%20%24lt%3Alifetime%20)%2C%2B%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20this%20prints%20out%20all%20the%20lifetimes%20passed%20to%20the%20macro%3A%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22lifetimes%3A%20%7B%7D%22%2C%20stringify!(%20%24(%20%24lt%20)%2C%2B%20))%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match_lifetime!(%20'a%2C%20'b%2C%20'static%2C%20'hello%20)%3B%0A%7D)

You can read more about the `lifetime` specifier in the [RFC](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1590-macro-lifetimes.md) or the [rust reference](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros-by-example.html#metavariables).

---

In case you just want to match the generics of a type you might be better off using [`tt`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/macros.html#macro-invocation) instead:

```rust
struct Example<'a, T>(&'a T);

macro_rules! match_generics {
    ( $typ:ident < $( $gen:tt ),+ > ) => {}
}

match_generics!( Example<'a, T> );
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&code=use%20std%3A%3Astringify%3B%0A%0A%23%5Ballow(dead_code)%5D%0Astruct%20Example%3C'a%2C%20T%3E(%26'a%20T)%3B%0A%0Amacro_rules!%20match_generics%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20(%20%24typ%3Aident%20%3C%20%24(%20%24gen%3Att%20)%2C%2B%20%3E%20)%20%3D%3E%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20println!(%22struct%3A%20%60%7B%7D%20%3C%20%7B%7D%20%3E%60%22%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stringify!(%20%24typ%20)%2C%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20stringify!(%20%24(%20%24gen%20)%2C%2B%20)%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20)%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%7D%0A%0Afn%20main()%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20match_generics!(%20Example%3C'a%2C%20T%3E%20)%3B%0A%7D)

Answer (score 0):

You can capture them as $exprs.

Comment: I've tried doing that and it doesn't seem to work for me. Here's a playpen: [http://is.gd/dNaiiS](http://is.gd/dNaiiS). Am I doing something wrong with it?

Comment: It needs to be an already-defined lifetime to work.  There's no real purpose to providing a particular name for a lifetime in this instance, since it's just being used as a generic parameter.  If a lifetime is already defined (as a label for a loop, for instance) then $expr works fine.  I can imagine it being useful if you had a trait or struct parameterized over a lifetime, though, and indeed I'm not sure if there's a way to do that (I've never needed to do it).

Comment: Here is a convoluted example of where it would be useful: http://is.gd/9Qj1H3. I wanted to use this, as I had a macro which would generate a function which was generic over a lifetime <'a>, as it accepted an argument parameterized by that lifetime. In my case, the body of the function usually wanted to return an arbitrary value, but sometimes it would want to return a value extracted from the argument, which only would live for the given lifetime.

Comment: @JW : `expr` doesn't seem to work, even in the case you mention: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=8b2585a1e173779cf420eca381fe319d

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create a new generic lifetime parameter from an argument given to your macro, then you have to match it with `$my_lifetime:tt` ([see playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=2d5564f2b44aaa05961d0b0fa1c2b31f)) :

```
macro_rules! my_macro {
    ($a:tt) => { struct MacroDefined<$a> { field: &$a str } }
}
```